# how to get JSON data from an API in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to get JSON data from an API in robot framework which has data with id's. I have to get the count of id's present in the data obtained from the API.

I have tried the below code:

```
${result} = get    ${API_JSON_PATH}
Should Be Equal  ${result.status_code}  ${200}
${json_data} =  Set Variable  ${result.content}
Log  ${json_data}
```

I am getting the below mentioned error:
No keyword with name '${result} = get' found.

Is the approach correct or is there any other better ways for getting the JSONS data?

Comment: Can you provide a full example of your code? It's hard to help you if we don't know which library you use. The appropriate formulation would require 4 spaces between `${result}` and `get` and `${API_JSON_PATH}` but as there is no keyword `Get` in  none of the libraries I know could be used (BuiltIn, Collections, RequestsLibrary or JSONLibrary) I'm wondering wether this is indeed a valid keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the RequestsLibrary and it's slide different from what you are doing.

the credential are not needed in your case but this is the example:

```
@{credential}=    Create List    Your_Username    Your_Password
Create Session    YOUR_API_ALIAS    YOUR URL    auth=@{credential}
${api}=    Get Request    YOUR_API_ALIAS    YOUR_URI
```

if you want get the content of the JSON:
${api.json()}

Documentation: https://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two or more spaces after the `=`. Robot looks for two or more spaces to find keywords and arguments, so it thinks your first statement begins with the keyword `${result} = get`. Since that's not a valid keyword, you get that error.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still i am getting the same error